# Joining DataFrames in Julia

Tags: dataframe, join, concatenation, julia

I am using v7.0 of DataFrames.jl and was wondering if the is a way to join two `DataFrame`s such that all columns that the two `DataFrame`s share in common are joined together while columns not common between both `DataFrame`s are labeled as missing.

The `join()` function seems create a new key for the `DataFrame`. 
The `vcat` function seems to not be able to concatenate `DataFrame`s without the exact same column names.

An example of what I meant below.

I want to combine

```
df1 = DataFrame(
    A = [1, 1000, 10000, 100000],
    B = [1,2,3,4],
    D = ["N", "M", "I", "J"])
df2 = DataFrame(
    A = [1,2],
    B = repeat(1:2, inner=1),
    C = ["hi","CE"])
```

in a way such that I get

```
df3 = DataFrame(
    A = [1,1000,10000,100000, 2],
    B = [1,2,3,4,2],
    C = ["hi", missing, missing, missing, "CE"],
    D = ["N", "M", "I", "J", missing])
```

I want to do this with large `DataFrame`s so adding keys isn't feasible manually.

Comment: it sounds like you want a full join. may I ask why `join()` didn't work for you? also, what version of Julia are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this in Julia v0.6.2 and DataFrames.jl v0.11.7:

```
join(df1, df2, kind = :outer, on = intersect(names(df1), names(df2)))
```

My output:

```
5×4 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ A      │ B │ D       │ C       │
├─────┼────────┼───┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1      │ 1 │ N       │ hi      │
│ 2   │ 1000   │ 2 │ M       │ missing │
│ 3   │ 10000  │ 3 │ I       │ missing │
│ 4   │ 100000 │ 4 │ J       │ missing │
│ 5   │ 2      │ 2 │ missing │ CE      │
```

Since it references the column names of `df1` and `df2` together, it should absolve you of naming keys manually.

Comment: Exact same output is received in Julia 1.0.1 and DataFrame 0.14.1

Comment: what is the syntax for `:`?

Comment: `ArgumentError: join function for data frames is not supported. Use innerjoin, leftjoin, rightjoin, outerjoin, semijoin, antijoin, or crossjoin`

Comment: @PatrickT this post is 2.5 years old. Julia has changed substantially since then (most recent version is v1.6.1). the function call may have changed, but the fundamental operation is still an outer join.

Comment: Would you consider updating your answer?